# Setting a combobox value in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

Access Combobox Problem with VBA

I have 2 forms in a single database, each with an unbund combobox on it.

When I read the record from a table I populate the various screen fields - including the comboboxes - from the data, but I am getting different responses on each screen.

Each combobox has 2 columns - the first (width zero) is the ID of another table, and the second (visible) column displays the name of the person who has that ID.

Screen/Combobox 1 - **working as desired**
This displays the name of the sponsor.

```
Me.cboSponsor = rstProgramme("intSponsor")
```

Screen/Combobox 2 - **not working as desired**
This one displays the ID of the manager (ie the intManager value)

```
Me.cboManager = rstRelease("intManager")
```

Both recordsets that hold the ID values are opened as dynasets like this:

```
Set rstProgramme = db.OpenRecordset("tblProgramme", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rstRelease = db.OpenRecordset("tblRelease", dbOpenDynaset)
```

I have compared the Properties of both comboboxes side by side, and they are identical, so I am stumped as to why one works and the other doesn't.

Can anyone suggest something I have missed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is your recordsource property set as for each combobox?

Comment: Why not use the built in query builder, to assign the Row Source property? You gain nothing from using vba, except more maintenance responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Only option left is that the table fields are differently configured.
Head to the table design view and compare both fields, Happened to me when I novicely configured lookup fields in tables.
Bad experience doing that kind of things.